# How does one give meta_key a name in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, meta-key

I am quite new to Wordpress and I have a question about meta_key. I saw a query to dispay custom fields of meta box that saved start and end dates. One of the parameters used in the query is the meta_key, but where does one find the name of the meta_key in the meta box? Or does one gives the meta_key a name? If so: how?

This question is a but basic perhaps and maybe it is not wel put, but i'm eager to learn. Things like meta_key seem to be fundamental, but it's so hard to find a explanation of these concepts in plain english.

Thanks in advance and regards, 
Louis

Answer (score 0):

Study this Codex article: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

> WordPress has the ability to allow post authors to assign custom
>   fields to a post. This arbitrary extra information is known as
>   meta-data. Meta-data is handled with key/value pairs. The key is the
>   name of the meta-data element. The value is the information that will
>   appear in the meta-data list on each individual post that the
>   information is associated with.

Comment: Thank you for quick response diggy, but I still don't get it The codex is not what I would call 'plain english':) If one would want to find the name of the meta_key of, eg, a meta box, where would one find this name of the meta_key and how did the meta box received the name for the meta_key? But thanks again for your response.

Comment: Let me specify what I mean when I say 'not what I would call plain english': Wordpress terms are explained in Wordpress jargon.

Comment: The easiest way to add, edit or delete meta keys + values is via the 'Custom Fields' meta box, to be found on the Edit Post admin page, right below the post editor. If it's hidden, check the screen options at the top right of the window.